# How can I understand this Matrix-output?

Tags: r

*GG* Hey there :)

Here is a thing I don't understand because I think I don't get the whole Mmatrix thing.

Let me explain: With the `sapply()` I have an x,y-argument. x is the argument N0 and y is the argument `"function(n) n* lambda^time"`. Obviously N0 consists of three variables (`N0<<-c(10,20,30)`). "time", which is part of the function-equation, consists of 5 variables (`time <-0:4`) thus I suppose the whole y-term consists of 5 variables. Then why is the head (very first "row" of the matrix [,1][,2][,3]) which must be related to N0 written like it contains the arguments of the sapply(,**Y**) -> vice versa the very first "column" of the matrix? I don't get it. Is my question understandable? Here the data:

```
N0 <- c(10, 20, 30)
lambda <- 2
time <- 0:4

Nt.s <- sapply(N0, function(n) n * lambda^time)
Nt.s
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]   10   20   30
[2,]   20   40   60
[3,]   40   80  120
[4,]   80  160  240
[5,]  160  320  480
```

Thanks!!! :)

Comment: OH I get it now! It changes place as n*lambda^time becomes N0 and N0 becomes the latter thing. OH!  :):):)

Answer (score 0):

It might help you if you better understand what `sapply` does. It's more or less equivalent to this:

Take the function `FUN <- function(n) n * lambda^time` and apply it in a loop to all elements of `N0`, i.e., call `FUN(N0[[1]]); FUN(N0[[2]]); FUN(N0[[3]])`. The results are then combined into a matrix.

Comment: Thank you :)  I kind of figured it out but didn't know how the function is made up (like how it can create  loop ;).... but that's probably something for the smart people...